# Internet Explorer Error

Tags: ajax, gridview, internet-explorer-8

The main error shown in IE is : ' Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.'
The error is displayed when the ExtJS framework tries to load a page containing a Ext grid component through an ajax request.

It works without problems in Firefox and Chrome.

Another error which is shown by IE is 'Expected identifier, string or number' which points to the line containing HTML inline style definition which is perfectly valid. I am not sure why this error is shown. I feel IE is pointing this error to the wrong place.

Could anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

"Could not complete the operation" errors in IE are usually caused by trying to modify the DOM before it is ready.

Move the JS so it fires in (for example) the onload event, or a JS library's ondomready event.

Comment: Thanks David, we are still not able to debug the error,

Here are the details, please let me know if you think of something.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; GTB6.4; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; eSobiSubscriber 2.0.4.16; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; InfoPath.2; AskTB5.6)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Apr 2010 08:59:42 UTC


Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0

Comment: URI: http://maverickous.com/iplbullets/ui/grouptabs.js.php?fb_sig_in_iframe=1&fb_sig_iframe_key=33e75ff09dd601bbe69f351039152189&fb_sig_locale=en_GB&fb_sig_in_new_facebook=1&fb_sig_time=1272445122.1546&fb_sig_added=1&fb_sig_profile_update_time=1269862698&fb_sig_expires=1272448800&fb_sig_user=717780378&fb_sig_session_key=2.S0HobzUh3hL2WTC4KieJFQ__.3600.1272448800-717780378&fb_sig_ss=S0HobzUh3hL2WTC4KieJFQ__&fb_sig_cookie_sig=ac56ee0d4ef238646383250fbc562b22&fb_sig_ext_perms=status_update,photo_upload,

Comment: video_upload,email,create_note,share_item,auto_publish_short_feed,publish_stream,auto_publish_recent_activity,contact_email&fb_sig_api_key=6535b5e4f6ef4fb9852ecabd9f75ec50&fb_sig_app_id=398355565395&fb_sig=1ab801ad237321e7bc7233f584b990a1

Comment: It would be great if you could share your email address and I can send you the details, as I am not able to paste the entire error message in 1 comment.

Comment: You can edit the original question to add more details (including images).

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a page using ajax and it has a inline script file like below  add // before 
the open comment tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--
  alert('text');
// -->
</script>
```

http://dracoblue.net/dev/could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101/137/